# How to convert user natural query into SQL query?

Tags: dialogflow-es, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am trying to build a chatbot in Rasa/Dialogflow, the problem i ham facing is to convert English to SQL query so that what user write in English can be converted into SQL fetch data from MYSQL database and display result to use.

Can someone suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally this is only possible through solutions like SEQ2SQL([Link here for reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.00103.pdf)).

But I implemented it in a workaround fashion:-

1. I got the json using `tracker.latest_message` .
2. After which I processed the json to make our own structured json like:

> [{'column_name':'a',
> 'operator': '=',
> 'value':'100'},
> {'column_name':'b',
> 'operator': '>',
> 'value':'100'}]

3. Above structure was used to form the where clause of the query.
4. Same way I made a custom json for Select Part as well :-

> [{sum:column1},{count:column2}]

5.Then I looped through the json I had created and made our queries.

Note:- This json Structure will not be able to cover all possible scenarios but worked decently for me.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail, how can i do it?

Comment: well sharing code will be a bit difficult because it is confidential but can explain you.
column_name and value in the above json are slots which are caught from user query.
Suppose if the person says: show me records where payment is 100
So, Columname:payement , value: 100, operator: =.
we will make the custom json structure which we will for loop to make the query.

Comment: Can you explain step by step process?

Comment: can you please explain which part you didn't understand?

Comment: Conversion of English text to JSON I believe and how i can query that to MYSQL database?

Comment: tracker.latest_message returns a predicted Json of the user query with all the slots which it has captured. Have you tried it

Comment: I will try and let you know? Thanks though highly appreciated.